# How to download embedded video for offline use

Tags: video-capture

I am trying to download a video from a webpage. I played around with developer tools in chrome and found out the video url.

I am able to play the video by going to the url in a new browser tab, but I cannot record the video in vlc. The url has the following format :

http://www.example.com/videos/video16x9.swf?instance=2014/W9.8-12.14&video=Reed-9-8-14.flv

Can somebody please give me suggestions on how to record the video for offline use ?

Comment: Have you tried [youtube-dl](https://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url you provided is does not seem to have any video on it.
Please check the url.

once you have the correct url you can download it using:

`wget` OR
`axel` OR
`IDM` (Internet Download Manager) [Windows] OR

you can make a dummy html page with `<a href="VIDEO_URL">click here</a>` line in it and open it in the browser and right click and choose save link as... This should work

you can also use Python's urllib library, as it uses a very obscure User-Agent in its request, i have downloaded many video using it, which usually fails with `wget` or `axel`

for this do following, after going to python shell:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("VIDEO_URL", "filename.flv")
```

Hope this helped.

**UPDATE**

The url that you are referring to is not the url to the video location, but instead to the swf player that is playing it. i checked the page for the original url, and it turns out that the video is not playing from an http stream but instead over rtmp, you can see it in the xml name `Reed-9-8-14.flv.xml` which get downloaded when the page loads.

Because of rtmp, their was no trace of any network activity corresponding to video download in the developer tools. but once you get the rtmp url of the video from the xml file you can use the linux utility called `rtmpdump` to download the video.

Answer (score -2):

When the video starts to play choose File>Save Page As in Chrome and it downloads.

You can also press <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on a Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in Windows.

Comment: that does't work. It just saves some file with size 37KBs (the video is obviously larger than that) with the name video16x9.swf .